What is 手堅いところ in this sentence?

雑誌は、三年ほど前に発売されたものだ。当時話題になっていた、とあるドラマの特集記事が読みたくて発売日に買った。


そのドラマとは、東京で起こった爆破テロ事件の真相をひとりの若手政治家が追う、というストーリーだった。


人気俳優やアイドル、名バイプレーヤーなど手堅いところを押えたキャストだったが、中でもひとり、銃撃や戦闘といったアクションシーンをこなす役者に椿は強く憧れた。

The character is reading a magazine about his favorite drama.
I generally get the gist of it, but I'm stuck on the first part of the last sentence.
I understand

中でもひとり、銃撃や戦闘といったアクションシーンをこなす役者に椿は強く憧れた。

Is essentially saying that "But 椿 actually strongly admired the actors performing all those actions scene.
However I'm quite ??? on this part

人気俳優やアイドル、名バイプレーヤーなど手堅いところを押えたキャストだったが

Specifically, what does ど手堅いところを押えた actually mean? From context I can gather he's saying the cast was very good, but I can't seem to understand why 押えた is being used here.


手堅い is "solid" or "(unsurprising but) safe" (as opposed to "unproven" or "challenging").
ところ after some adjectives can refer to people. See the definition 3㋓ in this entry.

名詞や形容詞・形容動詞の語幹に付いて、それにあてはまる人々の意を表す。「中堅—が脇を固める」「きれい—を集める」


押さえる in this context means "to secure" or "to (regard as important and) cover". The fourth and fifth definitions in this entry are relevant.

４ 自己に属するものとして確保する。また、差し押さえる。「制空権を—・える」「証拠を—・える」「財産を—・えられる」
５ 大切なところをしっかり理解する。把握する。「要点を—・える」



So 手堅いところを押さえたキャストだった means "It was a casting that covered solid choices".
